# Resource URL for Azure Devops Release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

with the latest release of Service principal and/or Managed Identity integration with Azure Devops, we plan to trigger the REST API via Managed identity :
[image]
for which we need the Resource URL for the Release pipelines.

Resource url for which Job should acquire a token from AAD in order to access the service

No where in any documentation or links I am able to get the list of all Resource URLs.
like for PowerBI it is : https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api

Can someone help provide what is the Resource URL for Azure Devops Release pipeline?
And is there any common site wherein you can get the values for all Azure/MSFT offerings

Below are the referenced Docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/service-principal-managed-identity?view=azure-devops

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP